# Overwriting a environment variable in linux

Tags: linux, unix

I wish to add a path to the `PATH` variable.

I have copied the `$PATH` variable into a file called `t1` using `echo`

```
echo $PATH > t1
```

I then edited t1

```
nano t1
```

I added my path `/usr/local/batch:` to the front of the path listing and saved t1.

Now I want to save t1 into $PATH and so overwriting $PATH. e.g.

`cat t1 > $PATH` (say) but I get "ambiguous redirect" warning.

I know it works as I read an example on how to do it on this forum but damned if I can find the answer again.

Comment: Do you really need the file? You could change the variable on the fly: `PATH="/usr/local/batch:$PATH"`

Comment: "Ambiguous redirect"... to the right of the ">" sign there must be a file name (or, at least, the shell interprets it as a file name). Of course, $PATH is not a file name (or, at least, you don't think it is). So your command IS wrong, and you are lucky that the shell noted something wrong and warns you.

Comment: I cheated. I changed operating system to windows and edited the environment file. Perfect.  I wanted to remove all unwanted paths as well as add my own paths - as I did in ms-dos. I am new to UNIX and not sure what the problem is with owning my own PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is a more general way to expand the `PATH` variable on a UNIX/Linux system:

```
export PATH=/this/is/the/new/directory:$PATH
```

Good luck

Comment: `PATH` will generally already be exported, so `PATH="/this/is/the/new/directory:$PATH"` without the `export` should work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to read PATH from a file:

```
export PATH=`cat t1`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an editor to edit a variable without, you could pipe it to the `vipe` utility from moreutils and then read it back.

```
PATH=$(printf '%s\n' "$PATH"|EDITOR=nano vipe)
```

(
For editing `PATH` specifically, I have a function that also translates `:` to newlines and back:

```
path_edit () 
{ 
    PATH="$(printf '%s' "$PATH" |tr : '\n'|vipe | tr '\n' : |sed 's/:$//')"
}
```

)

If you don't have `vipe`, you can replace it with:

```
vipe(){ sh -euc 't=; trap "rm -f $t" EXIT INT TERM; 
                 t=$(mktemp); cat>$t; ${EDITOR:-vi} $t <>/dev/tty>&0; cat $t'; }
```

Answer (score -2):

Because ">" will overwrite the contents of the file, you can try ">>".

Comment: Noooo. `$PATH` is an reference to an env variable that lives in the active process space of the running program (shell). Did you try your solution? Best to take this answer down as it will get downvoted and you'll lose reputation points.

Comment: Sorry. But a contributor on this forum did what I want in another question.  The contributor called it a hack and it works. Sorry to confuse you all.

Comment: How do I permanently remove a path from the "standard" path if I am not able to edit the path variable.